# at time when /at the time when

Tags: articles, definite-article

> As Swan said in The Current's debate, Pope Francis has no power to
>   change economic policy, but he does have the power to make us reflect
>   on our values **at time** when those values may need reconsideration.

[U.S. right accuses Pope of spreading anti-capitalist thoughts](http://www.cbc.ca/news/business/pope-visit-economics-1.3241774)

Do we need "**the**" in front of "time" here? If not, what is the difference between one with and without?

Comment: This is merely a typo; it should be "at a time".

Comment: I'm sure it's just a typo: it should be *at **a** time*, and the article just got dropped.

Comment: Yes, just look at this **[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+time+when%2Cat+a+time+when%2C+at+the+time+when&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20time%20when%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20a%20time%20when%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20time%20when%3B%2Cc0)** - "at time when" is attested at negligible levels compared with the variants with **the** and **a**.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it rests on an obvious typo.

Comment: Or "at times"..